# Which is the maximum number of Windows concurrent tcp/ip connections?

Tags: windows, tcp

In .NET I have already tried the configuration below successfully:

```
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="100"/>
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
```

Using 100 concurrent HttpWebRequest they answered almost simultaneously (less than a second).

I wonder why some people wrote in some forums that Windows XP and Windows Server 2008 limits this number to 15 or 20. They are right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be because people are confusing the number of inbound SMB connections with the number of TCP/IP connections.  SMB is used for file sharing and various other things and is limited to 10 connections in Windows Client OSes.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328459

Comment: @OrbMan.  Really, I have feeling you might be right. Do you have a supporting link?

Comment: Also, it's not an official utility, but on XP or Vista there's a utility available to let you alter this number of connections.

Answer (score 17):

The client versions of Windows are restricted in the number of half-open connections.

The `10` limit for **XP** is well known, **Vista** has other limits depending on the version (e.g. **Home Basic** has a limit of `2`, **Ultimate** has `25`).
You can Google "Patch for Event ID 4226" to alleviate these limits. Post **Vista SP2** the behavior is [configurable through a registry key](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969710).

**Windows Server** can handle several tens of thousands of concurrent inbound connections given enough resources.

Depending on your server version, you have to change some default parameters to allow these many connections to see [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-za/archive/blogs/david.wang/howto-maximize-the-number-of-concurrent-connections-to-iis6).

The author reports having seen `50.000+` concurrent connections to `IIS6` on `WS03SP1 x64` with `4GB` RAM.

Comment: Thx. I still wonder why it got downvoted before. Might be because of earlier inaccuracies while I was still editing. Still, it would be great if downvoters took the time to point out the fallacies in an entry and help build the knowledge.

Comment: "The 10 limit for XP is well known, Vista has other limits depending on the version (e.g. Home Basic has a limit of 2, Ultimate has 25)."
The answer above yours states that these are the SMB connection limits not the TCP connection limits.  That might be why you got a down vote?

Answer (score 5):

There are connection limitations on uncompleted (new) connections. IIRC, this was rolled into a update a few years ago as an experiment to curtail the spread of certain types of malware. You can safely remove this limit:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.12.network.aspx