# Maximum number of TCP connections in Python?

Tags: python, tcp, connection

I am working in Python on localhost. I wrote a raw server just read TCP socket, say in port 50001.

Then I tried max client connections:

```
def rawMultiConn(threadnum = 10000):
    g_event = threading.Event()
    def threadfn():
        sockets = [socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                   for i in range(threadnum)]
        for s in sockets:
            s.connect(('localhost', SERVER_PORT))
        g_event.wait()
        for s in sockets: s.close()

    t = threading.Thread(target = threadfn)
    t.start()
    g_event.set()
    t.join()
```

but after about 3000 connections, exception occurs:

> [Errno 10055] An operation on a socket could not be performed because
>   the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full

So how can I resolve it and max the connection?

Comment: Also see [How many socket connections possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/651665/608639) and [How many sockets can be created from a port?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/700594/608639)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `ulimit` and `quota` for the box and the user running the script.  `/etc/security/limits.conf` may also contain resource restrictions that you might want to modify.

Try running `ulimit -s unlimited`.

Also, `ulimit -n` will show the max number of open file descriptors/sockets allowed.  That may need modification as well.

---

**Some man pages and reference links:**

> - [ulimit](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?ulimit)
> - [quota](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?quota)
> - [limits.conf](http://ss64.com/bash/limits.conf.html)
> - [lsof](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof)

Comment: While the question didn't specify, a complete answer would also include other operating systems.