# How client know which socket connect to?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am using Java to do the socket programming as below.

Client program is as below:

```
 Socket MyClient;
    try {
           MyClient = new Socket("Machine name", PortNumber);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Server program is as below:

```
ServerSocket MyService;
    try {
       MyServerice = new ServerSocket(PortNumber);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.println(e);
        }

Socket clientSocket = null;
    try {
       clientSocket = MyService.accept();
        }
    catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Now my question is if I run more than one thread to open several sockets in one port (as the server code above), how my client program know which socket it is connecting to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how my client program know which socket it is connecting to?

The question doesn't make sense. It doesn't 'connect to a socket' at all, it connects to a listening port, and there is only one of those. Your server only accepts one client, so the second and subsequent threads will get an undefined behaviour ranging from a ConnectException to a ConnectionException to nothing, most probably the latter.

Comment: I saw some article said that we can create more than one socket from one port. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700594/how-many-sockets-can-be-created-from-a-port that is why I am confused. But your point make sense as well. How to interpret this thing?

Comment: I am getting more confused now, for my sample code, it totally follow the TCP/IP rule which is "one process run on one port", although it create multiple thread to do that....

Comment: @GMsoF The server can accept as many sockets as it likes from a single listening port. Your server doesn't do that. There is no such rule in TCP as 'one process one port'. If you did that, servers would be impossible to write.

Comment: OK, I think I almost get it. Allow me to ask one more question. If I have a program 'A' listening on port 1111 after that one client successfully connect to the socket A that was created in program A. While the socket A is being kept (communication is still going but program A is not listening on port 1111 anymore, it is enough with one socket), can program B listening on port 1111 and trying to create a socket B under port 1111 while socket A is still opened?

Comment: @GMsoF Yes but with difficulty. It's a very strange thing to do. The programs would have to co-operate to know when B could start listening, and the clients would also have to co-operate so that the one that expected to connect to A ran before the one that expected to connect to B. It would make much more sense to combine the servers. A port should only be used for one *protocol*. I think that is the sense of the 'rule' you cited above.

Answer (score 3):

Your client connects to the Servers port. So all clients will be having the same code
`MyClient = new Socket("Machine name", <port where server is listening>);`
The port opened at client side is not important. The client will get a free port available in his OS.

Comment: This is not what I ask. I want to know how the client know which socket that it is going to connect in server side? Because the server program create multiple thread to do that.

Comment: @GMsoF This is a perfectly reasonable answer, given that the question you asked doesn't actually make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your application knows it because you set it up with a specific port. There is no "auto discovery" built into TCP/IP, it's up to you to pick a server-port and make sure you set your clients up to connect to that port. Either you hard-code this into your client application or, better yet, have it in some configuration file you include with the client.

This is why you have a bunch of "known ports", like http is port 80. This means that a browser will **always** connect to port 80 on a web-server, unless you explicitly indicate another port in the URL.