# Multi-user application with ~200,000 connections at the same time

Tags: database, node.js, hosting, scalability

Hi Stackoverflow community!

I'm in charge of a backend for an event which will gather at least 200,000 spectators. They may all participate to a very simple Q/A game, either using a mobile application or a SPA website.

Having no experience with such a number of simultaneous users, I am wondering which kind of database, langage and server I should use for my backend.

I have previous experience in Node.js, MongoDB and socket.io, always with small projects, and was about to use them but some guys around me told me theses technologies can't handle such a lot of users and may lose some packets, or even crash.

It would be great if someone with much more experience in the field could give me advices about that matter!

Many thanks to all!

grebett

Comment: You might want to look at (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651665/how-many-socket-connections-possible)