# socket io app, CPU and RAM requirements

Tags: node.js, socket.io

What are the minimum requirements, CPU and RAM wise,
for a socket.io app which supports 10k-20k concurrent connections?
(does the requirements scale linearly?)
thanks

I'm guessing that the peak would be max 2000 messages at the same second.

Comment: There's a difference between 20k mostly idle socket.io connections and 20k socket.io connections that are regularly busy sending several messages per second. So, you probably need to describe something about the peak activity profile that you want to design for.  FYI, unless most sockets get busy at once or there's lots of processing involved in the messages, this is probably not CPU limited.

Comment: Thanks jfriens00, It would mainly be for chat purposes, so 10k-20k is the anticipated maximum active chatters. i'm guessing that the peak would be max 2000 messages at the same second.

Comment: Relevant articles: [How many socket connections possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9676852/816620), [the C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) and [Linux Kernel Tuning for C500k](http://urbanairship.com/blog/2010/09/29/linux-kernel-tuning-for-c500k/).