# How to properly deploy with Akka Cluster

Tags: scala, deployment, akka, akka-cluster

## Scenario

Right now we only have a single node running the whole system. What we want is to make a distinction between "frontend" nodes, and a single "backend" node.

- "Frontend" nodes (N nodes): Maintains a persistent connection with the clients through a WebSocket connection
- "Backend" node (1 node): Processes all the requests coming form all the frontend nodes querying to database, and handling the needed domain logic.

This distinction is needed due to some reasons:

- Do not reach the [limit of 70-100k persistent connections per frontend node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651665/how-many-socket-connections-possible)
- Avoid disconnecting the clients while deploying changes only affecting the backend

## Work done

We have connected the actors living on the frontend node with the ones living on the backend. We've done so instantiating the backend node `ActorRef`s from the frontend using the `akka.cluster.singleton.ClusterSingletonProxy`, and the `ClusterSingletonManager` while really instantiating them in the backend.

## Question

**How we do the deploy taking into account the Akka cluster node downing notification?**

As far as I understood by [the Akka Cluster documentation about downing](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdoc.akka.io%2Fdocs%2Fakka%2Fcurrent%2Fscala%2Fcluster-usage.html%23Downing&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNH5_RAsMAyXE4eoDRZTm_1cawT00Q), and [some comments on the akka mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/Sp_igF8QUZg), the recommended approach while dealing with that process would be something like:

1. Download the akka distribution from http://akka.io/downloads/
2. Copy and paste the `akka-cluster` bash script together with the `jmxsh-R5.jar` on a `resources/bin/` folder (for instance)
3. Include that folder on the distributed package (I've added the following lines on the `build.sbt`):

   `mappings in Universal ++=
   (baseDirectory.value / "resources" / "bin" * "*" get) map
   (bin => bin -> ("bin/" + bin.getName))`
4. While deploying, set the node to be deployed as down manually calling the bash script like:

   - Execute `bin/akka-cluster %node_to_be_deployed:port% down`
   - Deploy the new code version
   - Execute `bin/akka-cluster %deployed_node:port% join`

Doubts:

1. Is this step by step procedure correct?
2. If the node to be deployed will have the very same IP and port after the deploy, is it needed to make the `down` and `join`?
3. We're planning to set one frontend and the backend nodes as the seed ones. This way, all the cluster could be reconstructed while making a deploy only of the frontend nodes, or only to the backend one. Is it correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid downing manually, cleanup when a node is terminated, see:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/cluster-usage.html#How_To_Cleanup_when_Member_is_Removed

Regarding your points:

1. You do not need this procedure when the JVM is restarted and the cleanup code is executed. Only when the cleanup code somehow failed, you need to down manually as described in the procedure.
2. When the node is marked as removed by other nodes (after the cleanup code is executed), the same ip and port combination can be used to re-join the cluster.
3. Yes, you can just re-deploy a frontend node.

PS.:
- Coordinated shutdown will be improved in akka 2.5, see: 
https://github.com/akka/akka-meta/issues/38
- If you want to manage your cluster using a http API, see: http://developer.lightbend.com/docs/akka-cluster-management/current/

Comment: Hi @Bennie. Thanks for your response.
As I understand it, the cleanup process takes place when the node is removed and, by the [Akka Cluster documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/common/cluster.html#Membership_Lifecycle) I understand this as a further step (up -> unreachable -> down -> removed). 
My question is how to mark a node as down (up -> unreachable -> down). I've been playing with [ConstructR & Consul](https://github.com/Tecsisa/constructr-consul) but it doesn't deal with the down step (only with the seed nodes listing while joining a new member).