# Socket connection limit on Java?

Tags: java

I am running a Java multi threaded network application on my server and when I increase the thread count to more than 2000, I start seeing exceptions that it can not connect to an external server. "Connection refused" error. This is from the client side, I do not get errors when I do 1000 threads on different servers

Is there anyway to increase this limit?

Comment: 2000 threads... Mama mia

Comment: The limit is probably enforced on the server side, and in that case you can't do anything to increase it from the client side.

Comment: @Andremoniy It's running on a server with 20 cores with more than 80GB ram. The hardware can handle it

Comment: @abl it connects to a postgresql server. The server can handle many many more connections.

Comment: By default no. 2000 is toooo much

Comment: @Arya I don't know much about postgresql servers, but it seems sensible that there may be a (configurable) limit on the number of connections from a single source, to avoid DOS attacks, even if the server can handle many more connections. I could be wrong of course, but I think it's worth checking that. Have you found the limit to be _exactly_ 2000 threads?

Comment: @Arya : re-consider your design, you may want connection pool (eg C3P0 ), which will gently re-cycle your connections for whatever tasks you are doing

Comment: Seems related to [How many socket connections are possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/651665/697630)

Answer (score 1):

No doubts: each server has limit of incoming connections. On occupying all of them [DOS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) are based.

Comment: It is also worth to mention that 2000 connections doesn't make sense for client either.

Comment: @rkosegi as I said in my commentary above it is *Mamma mia..." :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using 'thread per connection' in Java is a bad idea when you are using 2000 connections. You might want to refer to Java NIO

Comment: This will address client side IO pressure, not fact that server rejects new connections.