# Why websocket server closes connections?

Tags: node.js, websocket

[image]

I have websocket nodejs server with ~2000 concurrent connections and server closes them periodically. I don't know the reason.
I catch it in my client code

```
 this.ws.onclose = function(){
        //try to reconnect in 5 seconds
        console.log("WS CLOSED. RECONNECT IN 5 SECS");
        setTimeout(function(){self.startNative()}, 5000);
    };
```

I start server with following code

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws');

//start websockets server
var webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer.Server({port: config.port2}, function () {
    console.log("Native websocket server process running on " + config.port2);
});

//websockets connection
webSocketServer.on('connection', function(ws, req) {
    ws.on('close', function() {
        //somecode
    });
```

What can cause it ?

Comment: Are the client and server on a LAN, or across the internet?

Comment: @JohnZwinck internet, not using ssl

Comment: Maybe this can help [How many socket connections possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651665/how-many-socket-connections-possible)

Comment: Are the channels sitent for long time? Try add a heartbeat/ping on a timed schedule.

Comment: @ArsenioSiani thx, but client can reconnect in 5 seconds, in 10 seconds, simultaneously

Comment: @socm_ can not understand your comment, you are complaining about the connection closed (when you want them alive). How long the socket connection stay _connected_ before it closes?

Answer (score 2):

Middleboxes on the internet will close connections that have seen no data for a long time (many minutes or hours).  You can resolve this by sending a "heartbeat" packet periodically, say once per five minutes.

It does not matter which direction originates the heartbeats, and the other side does not need to explicitly reply (but it could).  If the server is the one who sends heartbeats, this will also help the server to prune dead connections sooner.